# Forwarding Every new messages of a public channel

Tags: telegram, pyrogram

I want to write a bot with a program that forwards every single new message of a public channel to me.

For example, channel "A" posts a new message (this message can be varied on its types), and then my bot should immediately forward this new message to me.

I really appreciate it if you can comment any code sample for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Pyrogram's [Documentation](https://docs.pyrogram.org/) has several examples. You can use the Echobot example and adapt it to watch for a specific chat and use the bound method `.forward()` instead.

https://docs.pyrogram.org/start/examples/echobot

---

On another note; Bots can only exist as Admin in a channel. You'd have to ask the admins of the channel to add your bot as an admin, or you'll have to use a userbot. The Code itself will be the same in both cases, with the exception of the added bot token in your code/config.